# How to place text between author and date?

Tags: titles

```
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\title{Title}
\author{Author\thanks{ \footnotesize{Some Notes}}\\ \\ 1\\
2\\ \\ 3 \\4}
\date{\today}
%  \\ \\ \small{\textit{Latest version available \textbf{here}}}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

I want to have "Latest version available here" placed between 4 and the date. How can that be done? Also how can a link be added to the word "here"?

Comment: Using  `\maketitle` and  `titlepage` at the same time have no sense: Choose: (1) Use `\maketitle` and be in peac with what comes out, or (2) use `titlepage`  without using `\title` `\author`, `\date` and `\maketitle`, i.e., then  contents  and the format of this page  is up to you.

Comment: Have a look at package titlepages, which lists many examples: https://ctan.org/pkg/titlepages .

Answer (score 0):

You can find detailed examples of how to customize title pages here: [How to customize my titlepage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage)

As for including links, you can use the hyperref package and include your hyperlink as

```
Latest version available \href{http://www.latest.version}{here}.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\date{{\small\textit{Latest version available \textbf{here}}}\\ \medskip\today}
```